# Why remove this error? TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a code that takes a users id, then checks if it matches with one, if it does it sends a message...I keep getting the error **TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'**...

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx,message):
    member = message.author.id 
    if member == <userid>:
        await ctx.send("yo whats up")
    else:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not defining your function the way it should be. `on_message` event only takes in one argument: `message`. You will have to work without the `ctx` argument in `on_message` events. By taking that into consideration, you can re-format your current function code from:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx,message):
    member = message.author.id 
    if member == <userid>:
        await ctx.send("yo whats up")
    else:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

to:

```
@client.event
# Only pass in "message" argument
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author.id 
    if member == <userid>:
        # Use message.channel.send() instead of ctx.send()
        await message.channel.send("yo whats up")
    else:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: oh i see so the on_message can only have one argument. thank you so much!